# How to have hyperref pointing citations to the correct page?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing

I have a document with a customized bibliography. What I mean, is that the bibliography is done manually to insert custom stuff inside it. The following MWE illustrates my issue. The links generated by the `\cite` commands points to the first page of the document and not to the page where the bilio is. I guess this is the normal behavior, because I don't have `\bibliography` command. How can I solve this ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

%% Bibliography %%
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\newcommand{\itembib}[1]{\item[\cite{#1}] \fullcite{#1}}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
  @article{Article1,
    author={Manu},
    title={A nice paper},
    journaltitle={Journal 1},
    year=2017
  }
  @article{Article2,
    author={Max},
    title={A nice paper again},
    journaltitle={Journal 2},
    year=2016
  }
\end{filecontents} 
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

%% hyperref %%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks, linkcolor={red!50!black},
  citecolor={blue!50!black}, urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  TITLE
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{INTRODUCTION}
Blabla

\newpage
\section{BIBLIO}
\subsection{Subsec 1}
\begin{itemize}
  \itembib{Article1}
\end{itemize}
\subsection{Subsec 2}
\begin{itemize}
  \itembib{Article2}
\end{itemize}
\newpage
\section{CHAPTER 1}
Blabla\cite{Article1}.

\newpage
\section{CHAPTER 2}
Blabla\cite{Article2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you also have a real `\printbibliography` or do you do everything with your `\itembib`? What is `\itembib` for anway?

Comment: @moewe no I don't have `\printbibliography`. `\itembib` is shown on my MWE.

Comment: I see that `\itembib` is in your MWE I was just wondering whether you should better use `\printbibliography` with a few modifications instead of the hacky `\itembib`. If I knew what it is used for maybe I could find a way to make `\printbibliography` work for you (XY-problem). The immediate problem is that only entries in `\printbiblioghraphy` set an anchor to be linked to. `\fullcite` does not set an anchor (that makes sense because it is a citation command and citation command can be used multiple times for the same entry, but normally there is only one bibliography that contains an item)

Comment: What I want to achieve, is simply what i showed in the MWE: A custom bibliography section where papers are gathered under different sub and subsub sections with a particular order.

Comment: @moewe Isn't such a section/chapter wise bibliography possible with biblatex? You're the `bibliographies` expert here...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's what I thought as well. It all depends on how "custom" the section ought to be. I still think this could be an XY problem...

Comment: @moewe: I think your right (+1, by the way)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default `biblatex` only assigns a link anchor for an entry in the bibliography. In particular `\fullcite` does not get an anchor to link back to. This makes sense because the anchor for an entry should be unique and it is normally reasonable to assume that an entry will only occur in one bibliography. On the other hand, entries may be cited more than once and `\fullcite` is still at its heart a citation command.

You can use

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\blx@anchor%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
```

to make `\fullcite` produce the anchor that would normally be produced in the bibliography. Linking should then work as normal. Of course this goes horribly wrong if you `\fullcite` the same item more than once or if you use `\printbibliography` after all.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think `\itembib` is the ideal solution here. This may well be an XY problem...

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, and sorry for the acceptance delay, I have been fully busy with other stuff up to now. I am happy with this hack solution. Nevertheless I am not sure to understand what an "XY problem" is and would be happy to have a cleanest solution.

Comment: I am saying that I would be happy with a cleanest solution, because this one still have an incovenient: in my bibliography section I have hyperlinks to themselves. Indeeded, I am using the \cite command to define a biblio item :(

Comment: @ManuelSelva That depends on what you need. Maybe you can ask a new question explaining what you need your `\itembib` for and why you can't use `\printbibliography`. (XY Problem -> https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/35864)